# Validación personalizada en formulario con JSP

Tags: java

Necesito ingresar varios datos en un formulario (como nombre del producto, descripción, código del producto, valor, stock, etc)

Al ingresar todos los datos al formulario, este realiza validaciones, por ejemplo, que estén todos las cajas de textos con datos, de lo contrario muestra un error por pantalla, "debe llenar todos los campos", "falta ingresar el nombre del producto", etc....

Quiero agregar una validación personalizada para verificar adicionalmente que el código del producto sea distinto de cero, como haría esto en JSP ?

Código que uso :

```
  List errorMsgs = new ArrayList();
    try{

  int Codproducto = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("codproducto"));
  String nombreproducto=request.getParameter("nombreproducto");
  String Descripcion=request.getParameter("descripcion");
  String stock = request.getParameter("stock"); // este igual es INT
  String valor = request.getParameter("valor"); // INT

    //Aquí es donde necesito ayuda. Me sale este error "int cannot be dereferenced"
    if(Codproducto !=0 || Codproducto.trim().length()==0){
     errorMsgs.add("Debes ingresar un codigo del producto");

     //esto y lo de abajo funciona bien. Al parecer el error es por la conversion de String a Int ¿?
  if(nombreproducto==null||nombreproducto.trim().length()==0){
      errorMsgs.add("Falta ingresar el nombre del producto");   

      }
  if(Descripcion==null||Descripcion.trim().length()==0){
      errorMsgs.add("Falta ingresar la descripcion del producto");
      }
```

Comment: Utilizas métodos trim y length sobre un int, puede ser eso.

Answer (score 1):

Refactorizo tu código:

```
List<String> errorMsgs = new ArrayList();
  try{
   int codProducto = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("codproducto"));
   String nombreproducto=request.getParameter("nombreproducto");
   String descripcion=request.getParameter("descripcion");
   String stock = request.getParameter("stock"); // este igual es INT
   String valor = request.getParameter("valor"); // INT

   if(esParametroValido(codproducto)) {
     errorMsgs.add("Debes ingresar un codigo del producto");
   }
   if(esParametroValido(nombreproducto)){
     errorMsgs.add("Falta ingresar el nombre del producto");   
   }
   if(esParametroValido(descripcion)){
     errorMsgs.add("Falta ingresar la descripcion del producto");
   }

}

//metodo para validar parametros de tipo int
private boolean esParametroValido(int valorDeParametro) {
  return valorDeParametro == null ? false : true;
}

//metodo para validar parametros tipo String
private boolean esParametroValido(String valorDeParametro) {
  return valorDeParametro == null || valorDeParametro.isEmpty() ? false : true;
}
```

Lo único que he definido es un método de validación por cada tipo de parámetro, el error es porque un tipo *int* puede ser nulo, pero evidentemente no tiene métodos, *no es un objeto, es un tipo primitivo*, su clase equivalente que es **Integer**, y esa si es un tipp de clase, que tampoco dispone de los métodos *length()* ni *trim()* que son propios de la clase **String**

Answer (score 0):

Para comprobar que el valor de una variable sea distinto de cero, en jsp, sería algo así:
Primero creas el objeto.

```
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="codigo">
```

Y luego donde lo quieras validar, lo recoges y validas.

```
if (request.getParameter("codigo" != 0)){
     Código con el que se cumple esa condición
}else{
     Código si no se cumple esa condición.
}
```

¿Más o menos?

Comment: Y que tal una solución jstl